# Get Const::PTR from message

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

For a specific function that is not a callback, I require a `const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& image_pointer` to work with that is derived from a regular `sensor_msgs::Image source_image` that I already have.

How would one get such a constant image pointer from a regular message?

Thanks!
Ruud

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196697/get-const::ptr-from-message/) by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2014-11-04

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If its no problem for your that the data is copied you can do something like:

```
sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr your_const_pointer( new sensor_msgs::Image( source_image ) );
```

Note that, this calls the copy constructor of sensor_msgs::Image thereby copying the underlying data. (But I guess its Ok for you because you want ConstPtr)

If you need a shared pointer that can modify the data in your original object this is not possible in this way because you cannot (safely) create a shared_pointer for a object you do not have the ownership for  ( Unless you already have a shared_pointer (, which you don't,) and the object you intend to point to does not implement boost enable_shared_from_this (which message types do not) ) ....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on 2014-11-04**:
Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For reference, ImagePtr and ImageConstPtr are defined as:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::sensor_msgs::Image> ImagePtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::sensor_msgs::Image const> ImageConstPtr;
```

The quickest legal solution would be to create an ImageConstPtr with a null deleter, so that when the shared_ptr is destructed, it doesn't try to deallocate the memory. You would also have to be careful that the shared_ptr doesn't outlive your `source_image` object.

```
ImageConstPtr image_pointer(*source_image, boost::null_deleter());
```

However, this is not by any means the 'right way'. The best thing to do would be to initialize your `source_image` object as an ImagePtr in the first place, and simply pass it to the function expecting an ImageConstPtr.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-11-04**:
Or use Wolf's suggestion to copy the data :)

**Comment by [xkortex](https://answers.ros.org/users/38843/xkortex/) on 2021-02-01**:
This is a great trick when you are willing to trade a bit of safety/readability for performance.